# How to get a child component to remove itself from the parent component using Remix

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component and a child component. The parent component has a button that adds a child component to its user interface. The child component has a button that removes itself from the page.

It works except that the `removeChild` function only keeps the state that existed up until the child component was created. So if the function is called, all of the child components that were created after that are lost. For example, if 5 child components were added and the third one is removed, then the fourth and fifth are lost because they didn't exist when the third one was created.

How would I get this to work using Remix?

```
export default function ParentComponent() {
    const [childComponents, setChildComponents] = useState ([]);

    const removeChild = (i) => {
        console.log ('removing', i);
        setChildComponents (childComponents.toSpliced (i, 1));
    };
    const addChild = () => {
        setChildComponents ([...childComponents, <Child key={childComponents.length} i={childComponents.length} remove={removeChild} />]);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={addChild}>Add Child</button>
            <div>{childComponents}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default function Child ({i, remove})
{
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {remove (i);}}>Delete Me</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use functional state updates to avoid stale closure issues. This allows the code to update from the current state value versus whatever is closed over in callback function scope.

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [childComponents, setChildComponents] = useState([]);

  const removeChild = (i) => {
    console.log("removing", i);
    setChildComponents((childComponents) => childComponents.toSpliced(i, 1));
  };
  
  const addChild = () => {
    setChildComponents((childComponents) =>
      childComponents.concat(
        <Child
          key={childComponents.length}
          i={childComponents.length}
          remove={removeChild}
        />
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addChild}>Add Child</button>
      <div>{childComponents}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-a-child-component-to-remove-itself-from-the-parent-component-using-re]

A more correct method to avoid this issue is to store only the child ids in the parent state and render the `childComponents` by mapping them to the `Child` components. This avoids closing over stale state "snapshots" when storing JSX in React state, which is a React anti-pattern.

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [childComponents, setChildComponents] = useState([]);

  const removeChild = (i) => {
    console.log("removing", i);
    setChildComponents((childComponents) => childComponents.toSpliced(i, 1));
  };

  const addChild = () => {
    setChildComponents((childComponents) =>
      childComponents.concat(childComponents.length)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addChild}>Add Child</button>
      <div>
        {childComponents.map((id) => (
          <Child key={id} id={id} remove={removeChild} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ id, remove }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={remove.bind(null, id)}>Delete Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-a-child-component-to-remove-itself-from-the-parent-component-using-re (forked)]